# is it possible to check if the sentence include a certain word using keyword type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I have a question about type keyword in typescript.
you can see the below code.
the argument has to include the word ('api') in the prefix.
of course, I can check it using coding such as `indexOf`.
but I want to use the type keyword only.

```js
interface SomethingParam {
  url: string
}
function check(url: SomethingParam) {
  console.log(url);
}

check({ url: 'foobar' }) // error
check({ url: 'api/foobar' }) // ok
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try like it

```
function check(url: `api/${string}`) {
  console.log(url);
}

check('foobar') // error
check('api/foobar') // ok
```

Comment: thank you so much !! it is easier than I thought ㅠㅠ